# Using jsonnet to update Prometheus operator default rule

Tags: prometheus-operator, jsonnet

I am trying to override the Default rules in Kube-Prometheus-Stack.
I have enabled default rules when Kube-Prometheus-Stack was deployed.
I tried with jsonnet as shown in this example https://github.com/prometheus-operator/kube-prometheus/blob/master/docs/developing-prometheus-rules-and-grafana-dashboards.md.

But I think I am not following the steps correctly so its not working as expected.

I followed the below steps..Kindly validate and please let me know what I am missing here.

Created a jsonnet file (my-custom-update.jsonnet) to update a rule "KubePodCrashLooping",

```
 local filter = {
  prometheusAlerts+:: {
    groups: std.map(
      function(group)
        if group.name == 'kubernetes-apps' then
          group {
            rules: std.filter(function(rule)
              rule.alert != "KubePodCrashLooping",
              group.rules
            )
          }
        else
          group,
      super.groups
    ),
  },
};
local update = {
  prometheusAlerts+:: {
    groups: std.map(
      function(group)
        if group.name == 'kubernetes-apps' then
          group {
            rules: std.map(
              function(rule)
                if rule.alert == "KubePodCrashLooping" then
                  rule {
                    expr: "kube_statefulset_status_replicas_ready{job=\"kube-state-metrics\",statefulset!=\"vault\"} != kube_statefulset_status_replicas{job=\"kube-state-metrics\",statefulset!=\"vault\"}"
                  }
                else
                  rule,
                group.rules
            )
          }
        else
          group,
      super.groups
    ),
  },
};
local kp = (import 'kube-prometheus/kube-prometheus.libsonnet') + filter + update + {
    prometheusAlerts+:: (import 'prometheus-rules.json'),
};

{ ['00namespace-' + name]: kp.kubePrometheus[name] for name in std.objectFields(kp.kubePrometheus) } +
{ ['0prometheus-operator-' + name]: kp.prometheusOperator[name] for name in std.objectFields(kp.prometheusOperator) } +
{ ['node-exporter-' + name]: kp.nodeExporter[name] for name in std.objectFields(kp.nodeExporter) } +
{ ['kube-state-metrics-' + name]: kp.kubeStateMetrics[name] for name in std.objectFields(kp.kubeStateMetrics) } +
{ ['alertmanager-' + name]: kp.alertmanager[name] for name in std.objectFields(kp.alertmanager) } +
{ ['prometheus-' + name]: kp.prometheus[name] for name in std.objectFields(kp.prometheus) } +
{ ['prometheus-adapter-' + name]: kp.prometheusAdapter[name] for name in std.objectFields(kp.prometheusAdapter) } +
{ ['grafana-' + name]: kp.grafana[name] for name in std.objectFields(kp.grafana) }
```

Build this jsonnet file with the build.sh script provided in the document,

```
./build.sh my-custom-update.jsonnet
```

This has actually deleted the "KubePodCrashLooping" rule instead of updating it.
This created all the yaml files under manifests directory

I think I am missing something..Please advice.

Comment: Your local is missing the body. You need an expression after the final `;` in your snippet.

Comment: @sbarzowski ..Thankyou for the response..
I have updated the code now..This time no error.I have added local kp to update the body.I am not sure if this is right way.But Its deleting the rule instead of updating it.Please advice.

Comment: Please inspect the generated YAML files. Can you find the updated rule there?

Answer (score 1):

I got it working now,

```
local kp = (import 'kube-prometheus/kube-prometheus.libsonnet') +{
_config+:: {
namespace: 'monitoring',
},
prometheusAlerts+:: {
groups:
std.map(
function(group)
if group.name == 'kubernetes-apps' then
group {
rules: std.map(function(rule)
if rule.alert == "KubeStatefulSetReplicasMismatch" then
rule {
expr: "kube_statefulset_status_replicas_ready{job=\"kube-state-metrics\",statefulset!=\"vault\"} != kube_statefulset_status_replicas{job=\"kube-state-metrics\",statefulset!=\"vault\"}",
labels: {
priority: 'P1',
severity: 'info',
},
}
else
rule
,
group.rules
)
}
else
group,
super.groups
),
},
};


{ ['00namespace-' + name]: kp.kubePrometheus[name] for name in std.objectFields(kp.kubePrometheus) } +
{ ['0prometheus-operator-' + name]: kp.prometheusOperator[name] for name in std.objectFields(kp.prometheusOperator) } +
{ ['node-exporter-' + name]: kp.nodeExporter[name] for name in std.objectFields(kp.nodeExporter) } +
{ ['kube-state-metrics-' + name]: kp.kubeStateMetrics[name] for name in std.objectFields(kp.kubeStateMetrics) } +
{ ['alertmanager-' + name]: kp.alertmanager[name] for name in std.objectFields(kp.alertmanager) } +
{ ['prometheus-' + name]: kp.prometheus[name] for name in std.objectFields(kp.prometheus) } +
{ ['prometheus-adapter-' + name]: kp.prometheusAdapter[name] for name in std.objectFields(kp.prometheusAdapter) } +
{ ['grafana-' + name]: kp.grafana[name] for name in std.objectFields(kp.grafana) }
```